# Unscope a default scope by joins asociation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class House
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :house
  default_scope { joins(:house}.where.not("house.status": deleted) }
end
```

i want to know how to unscope `where.not("houses.status": deleted)` when i call `House.first.items` not have `WHERE ("houses"."status" != deleted)`

this default_scope is important, can not remove it T.T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
House.first.items.unscoped
```

Anyway, I'd use `default_scope` very rarely

If you want to unscope just a where condition you can do

```
House.first.items.unscope(where: [:status])
```

But you have to change your `default_scope` declaration using an hash

```
default_scope { joins(:house}.where.not(status: deleted) }
```

See: *[ActiveRecord::Scoping::Default::ClassMethods#unscoped](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped)*

Comment: it will generate something like `SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" LIMIT $1`, and not have some query, anything else? plz

Comment: Try `unscope(where: [:status])`

Comment: But you have to define your default_scope with hash, not string `default_scope { joins(:house}.where.not(status: deleted) }`

Comment: Great. My pleasure